# Android Master-Detail FullScreen of SurfaceView in detail fragment

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I'm developing an Android app with Master-Detail template that works only in landscape mode. In the detail fragment I have a SurfaceView with a mediaplayer and I want to give to the user the possibility to play the video in fullscreen mode.

How can achieve this result?